# Inclined Bars in Python Bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple bar chart created in python and I want to make only bars inclined and x and y axis shouldn't be changed but couldn't figure out how to do. It is possible such a property?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, width, fill=False, ,align='center', linewidth = linewidth, alpha=0.6, color = 'gray')
plt.xticks(y_pos, words)
plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: `plt.bar` can't do that but you can draw your own bars.

Comment: @Goyo Apparently you understood the question. Would you mind editing it such that everyone can?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest All I understand is that the OP wants inclined bars. Isn't that clear enough in the question as is? I am hesitant to edit because other important details that I did not get right might go away and I think the question really screams "I want inclined bars" and maybe something more.

Comment: Actually I try to make my plotting images inclined and I thought I might do it in the beginning. Maybe the procedure for images to make straight vertical lines inclined will also help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to obtain?

```
import math
def tilt_rectangle(rect, angle=math.pi/4):
    verts = p.axes.transData.inverted().transform(rect.get_verts())
    verts[2,0] += p.get_height()*math.tan(angle)
    verts[3,0] += p.get_height()*math.tan(angle)
    poly = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(verts)
    p.axes.add_artist(poly)
    poly.update_from(rect)
    return poly


x = np.arange(4)
y = np.random.random(size=(4,))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
b = plt.bar(x, y)
for p in b.patches:
    poly = tilt_rectangle(p)
    poly.set_clip_on(False)
    p.remove()
```

[image]